# Why I am getting Template execution error in Play framework?

Tags: json, playframework

I am trying to display a list to my page and I want to sort it by **purchaseTime** ascending, but I got this error and I can't solve it.

HTML:

```
#{list items:orderList.sort(), as:'orders'}
<div class="divs">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><p >${orders_index}</p></li>
            <li><p >${new Date(orders?.get("purchaseTime").getAsLong()).format('yyyy/MM/dd')}</p></li>
            <li><p >${new Date(orders?.get("purchaseTime").getAsLong() + 86400000).hoursRemaining()}</p></li>

            <li><p ></p>XDCFG0006</li>
            <li><p >${orders?.get("orderID").getAsString()}</p></li>
            <li><p ><a href="/us_en/Quickreview">Quick review</a></p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
#{/list}
```

And I got this error when I load it:

> Template execution error
>   Execution error occured in template /app/views/Application/dashboard.html. Exception raised was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: com.google.gson.JsonArray.sort() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: wait(), size(), wait(long), get(int), split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(long, int).

In /app/views/Application/dashboard.html (around line 126)

I have error in this line.

```
#{list items:orderList.sort(), as:'orders'}
```

Comment: What type is the "orderList" and What's the signature of "sort" method?

Comment: It looks like your `orderList` is a gson `JsonArray`, which doesn't provide a `sort` method. Have a look at sorting the data in the play action before serialising it to Json.

Comment: Thanks  Reza Same'e and Shadowlands for your time, I solved it. I tried using Angular, and it works fine now... :) :)